# Setting up meta data for a Rails Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metadata

I have been struggling to figure out how to place my meta data for all pages. The `head` tag where the meta data must be placed is on `application.html.erb`. My approach at first which I later found as a bad practice was to check the URL path, like: `if request.original_fullpath == '/faq'` to show the meta data for the FAQ page.

Despite being a bad practice, this couldn't help on pages that are dynamic (like the user's profile pages). Then I decided to take a simple approach and make it work. I added the meta tags on each page individually. I was naive thinking that can be overridden by using the head tag on each page. So I was wondering, how do I set the meta tags/data for each page on Rails? What's your approach?

Comment: You could take a look at [meta-tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags). With this gem, you should be able to set meta tags for each template directly in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) helper might work well.

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  <%= content_for :meta_tags %>
</head>

# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<% content_for :meta_tags do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that you hyperlinked the content_for. Thanks!